Exercise of finite étale algebra and $G \subseteq \mathrm{Aut}_R(A)$
I have been stalling on the resolution of an exercise I have come across.
Let $R$ be a commutative ring with connected $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ and let $A$ be a non-null finite étale $R$-algebra with connected $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$. Let $G \subseteq \mathrm{Aut}_R(A)$ be a finite subgroup.
I would like to show the following: We have $R = A^G$ if and only if the following $A$-algebra morphism is actually an isomorphism:
$$\gamma : A \otimes_R A \longrightarrow \mbox{Hom}_{\mbox{Sets}} (G,A)$$
such that
$$a \otimes b \mapsto (g \mapsto a \cdot g(b)).$$

My attempts.
$(\Longleftarrow)$ We can immediately observe that, since $R$-algebra automorphisms fix $R$, then $R \subseteq A^G$.

Now, I have seen that that $A \otimes_R A$ is a finite étale $A$-algebra meanwhile $A^G$ is finite étale $R$-algebra. I would like to show that actually $A \otimes_R A$ is a finite étale $R$-algebra, so I can apply a lemma I have seen in my course (the professor referenced Lenstra's Galois theory for Schemes, but I could not find it in there) which guarantees me that there exists $C$ finite étale $R$-algebra which is faithfully flat and such that
$$A \otimes_R C \cong C^E \cong C^{|E|}$$
as $C$-algebras (for a suitable set $E$). From this we have that
$$(A \otimes_R A) \otimes_R C \cong C^{|E|^2} \mbox{  and  } A^G \otimes_R C \cong (A \otimes_R C)^G \cong (C^{|E|})^G \cong C^{|E| \cdot |G|} .$$
From this, with a lemma I have seen that



is a commutative diagram where $\overline{\gamma}$ is induced by a set function
$$H : G \times E \longrightarrow E^2 .$$
Since $\gamma$ is an isomorphism, then $\overline{\gamma}$ is isomorphism, then $H$ is a bijection, i.e. $|G| \times |E| = |E|^2$, so $|G| = |E|$. Finally we can see that
$$A^G \otimes_R C \cong (A \otimes_R C)^G \cong (C^{|E|})^G$$
where, considering the action of $G$ on $C^{|G|}$ we have $(C^{|E|})^G \cong C$, so
$$A^G \otimes_R C \cong C \cong R \otimes_R C$$
and we finally use faithfull flatness of $C$ to conclude $A^G \cong R$. Putting toghether the latter with $R \subset A^G$, we get $A^G = R$, as wanted.
$(\Longrightarrow)$ We suppose $R = A^G$ and consider $\gamma$.

Surjective. Since the category of finite étale $R$-algebras is a Galois category, we have the decomposition $\gamma = \gamma^{\prime \prime} \circ \gamma^\prime$ with
$$\gamma: A \otimes_R A \xrightarrow{\gamma^\prime} \mbox{ Im} (\gamma) \xrightarrow{\gamma^{\prime \prime}} A^G \cong A^{|G|} .$$
Now, I should have Im$(\gamma) \cong A^m$ for $1 \le m \le |G|$ ... and I don't have any ideas on how to continue.
Injective. Now, considering the diagram in the picture above (without, now, the knowledge of $\gamma$ being an isomorphism), we have that, since $\gamma$ is surjective (we use what we have not yet proved above) we have that $\overline{\gamma}$ is induced by $H$ injection, hence $|G| \le |E|$.

We also have that
$$C \cong R\otimes_R C = A^G \otimes_R C \cong (A \otimes_R C)^G \cong (C^E)^G$$
This implies, looking at the action, that $|G| \ge |E|$, hence $H$ is bijective, hence $\overline{\gamma}$ is isomprhism, hence $\gamma$ is isomorphism.

In particular I would like to know if the proof is good, apart from the phrases in bold which need further proof:

(i) I would like to show that actually $A \otimes_R A$ is a finite étale $R$-algebra;

(ii) ... and I don't have any ideas on how to continue. : surjectivity of $\gamma$.
Also, any help with those two points, as well as any comments on the proof or any alternative "cleaner" argument, would be gratly appriciated.

I think the initial formulation of the claim didn't make sense, since the action appears in both sides of the equivalence, so it should be part of the given data. Please double check my edit.

That the tensor product of étale algebras is still étale is standard and can be found for example ... really you can also enter it in Google and find the proof. "Tensor product étale algebra stacks project" leads to https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03PC resp. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00U2 I don't see a point of reproducing it here unless you have a specific problem with the standard proof.
